# Squarespace Change pageSize limit on getting blog posts

Tags: json, ajax, offset, squarespace

i'm working on a Squarespace Website, i have a blog with several posts, actually 36 posts, using ajax call i parse all the posts with the following url [url to parse](https://rudolf-buchbinder.squarespace.com/timeline-list-v7?format=json), the problem is that SQS return only 20 items, and the other items should be parsed again with the offset returned :

```
"pagination": {
  "nextPage": true,
  "nextPageOffset": 1518167880210,
  "nextPageUrl": "/timeline-list-v7/?offset=1518167880210",
  "pageSize": 20
},
```

So if i have 100 or 500 posts created i should do 1 ajax call to get 20 posts each time (5 or 28 calls)? SQS forums doesn't give a solution for that. is there any param that i can give to the url that might give me more items than 20?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no parameter that can return more results than what the collection's `pagesize` property is set to.

However, there are ways to get more than 20 results, **both of which require [developer mode](https://developers.squarespace.com/quick-start) to be enabled**.

The first option is to set the collection's `pagesize` property in the [.conf file](https://developers.squarespace.com/collections/) to a [number higher than 20](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/5769/can-i-change-the-posts-per-page-value.html). That should cause your requests to return that number of items.

```
"pageSize" : 999,
"forcePageSize" : true
```

Keep in mind that increasing the pagesize in this way may increase page load times within that collection.

The second option is to use a [custom query tag](https://developers.squarespace.com/squarespace-query/) (`<squarespace:query>`) and embed a `<script>` within its scope. Within the query, you could set the limit to up-to 100. The script could then have access to store the collection data to the global window object for use by another script outside that context (for example). But this will only help you up to 100 results, not 500.

If neither of those work (both require dev. mode), then I think you are left with a recursive AJAX request as your only option...one that continues to pull item data 20 at a time until all items are gathered.

Hope those ideas help.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I'm aware of this solution but my client doesn't agree with enabling develper mode, i'm looking for a solution by passing params to the url, otherwise how can i use '<squarespace:query>'   with my case? does it need developer mode?

Comment: Yes, using `<squarespace:query>` also requires dev. mode.