# What is the best way to debug a custom Squarespace JSON-T web application?

Tags: javascript, json, squarespace, jsontemplate

So, a few years ago (2019), I built a custom Squarespace web application for one of my Church's podcast channels. They were using Squarespace for all of their web properties, so that's what I had to work with. I took a standard HTML template, deconstructed how to follow Squarespace's templating system, and used a combination of their JSON-T markup paired with the JSON data every Squarespace page returns to establish a functional system of calling the blog/podcast data (aka, collections) and populating archives/single posts accordingly.

At some point, Squarespace introduced 7.1 and things slowly got weird. I noticed that podcast posts were beginning to produce superficial console errors on their backend - but everything was still functional (sort of like the kind of syntax errors you could get with a schema markup, but overall type designation still works). Fast forward to now, the Squarespace markup is just not behaving as expected.

I've included the problematic code for reference.

```
<squarespace:query collection="podcast" skip="1">
{.repeated section items}
<div class="col-sm-12 mb-40 catchItems">
<div class="podcast-card full">
<figure class="podcast-image">
<a href="{website.fullUrl}{fullUrl}">
<img src="{assetUrl}" alt="{title}" title="{title}" /></a></figure>
<div class="podcast-content">
<span class="podcast-date">{addedOn|date %B %e, %G}</span>
<h2 class="podcast-title">
<a href="{website.fullUrl}{fullUrl}">{title}</a></h2>
<p class="podcast-excerpt">
<a href="{website.fullUrl}{fullUrl}">{excerpt}</a></p>
<ul class="podcast-meta">
<li class="item">
<a href="{website.fullUrl}{fullUrl}" class="podcast-play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i> Play Episode</a></li>
</ul></div></div></div>
{.end}
</squarespace:query>
```

Normal behavior would call ALL the podcasts, but that is not what's happening.

Upon viewing the "page source", the collection stops enumeration after 20 posts (which it did not do previously), and there doesn't appear to be any settings in their CMS backend to explain the change. All the pods still exist on Squarespace's backend.

As there doesn't appear to be any errors in the code itself (not that I really have any options when it comes to debugging their platform), I'm not really sure where to go from there.

What's worse is that Squarespace's JSON-T documentation is mediocre at best. Squarespace may have changed or updated how their JSON-T works. Or not. I can't tell. Their documentation doesn't appear to make any references one way or the other.

I had to patch together my understanding based on other dev stories and blogs. Their support team won't touch it and has historically been underwhelming.

Does anyone with JSON-T/Custom Squarespace dev experience know what's going on here? Does anyone know how or have a method to debugging JSON-T for errors? All leads are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How many podcasts are there in total? Unfortunately `<squarespace:query>` has a limit of 100: https://developers.squarespace.com/custom-query-tag . This could be worked around by using repeated/looped JavaScript/AJAX requests, determining whether you've reached the end of the collection (using the `pagination` property), and then outputting the markup using your own JavaScript template (template literal, Mustache.js, etc.). Those are some ideas for starters which, admittedly, do not address your broader question regarding an approach to debugging which has always been a challenge.

Comment: Thanks for this! If you said this as the answer, I would've marked it correct - as it appears to be at the root of the collection issue. It's also corroborated on this stack post pertaining to pageSize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721404/squarespace-change-pagesize-limit-on-getting-blog-posts. I'll leave the Q open in hopes someone has a clever debug workaround.